# Qt not removing item from layout

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple Qt application that dynamically adds and deletes items from the layout, but it does not work, so I wrote the code below to illustrate what I'm doing:

The header file justs put an additional `layout` field in addition to Qt creator template:

```
mainwindow.h

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QVBoxLayout>>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QFrame* create_frame();
    void remove_frame();
    QVBoxLayout* layout;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The cpp file adds a few QFrame to the current layout, then clicking the button will remove them one by one. The `QCoreApplication::processEvents` and `QThread::sleep` just adds some animation to show what is happening.

```
mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QThread>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto window = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(window);

    auto button = new QPushButton(window);
    button->setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100);
    layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    window->setLayout(layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        auto x = create_frame();
        layout->addWidget(x);
    }

    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::remove_frame);

}

void MainWindow::remove_frame() {
    while(layout->count() > 0) {
        auto item = layout->itemAt(0);
        layout->removeItem(item);
        delete item;
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        QThread::msleep(200);
    }

}

QFrame* MainWindow::create_frame() {
    auto x = new QFrame();
    x->setMinimumHeight(20);
    x->setMaximumHeight(20);
    x->setFrameStyle(QFrame::StyledPanel);
    return x;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The animation is a mess, and does not completely remove all the QFrame boxes. What did I do wrong here? And later I find that if I use `auto item = layout->itemAt(0)->widget(); layout->removeWidget(item);` then I can indeed remove them, are `removeItem` and `removeWidget` doing different things?

Comment: Not an answer but somehow related - FYI: [qgridlayout add and remove sub layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398153/7478597). The `QLayoutItem` is actually an "intermediate" instance which is inserted internally if you add a widget or layout to a layout. I'm really not sure what happens with the "child" widget if you remove the layout item. It might be that it's still child of the parent widget. (It's still there but just not layouted anymore.) Please, note that the ownership of a widget is the responsibility of its parent widget but not the layout.

Comment: I believe to fix your issue your have to remove the layout item from the parent layout _and_ the widget from its parent widget. (For the latter, it might be sufficient just to delete it. If I remember right the destruction removes it from its parent internally. Alternatively, you can set the parent of the widget (to delete) to a `nullptr` (to remove it from its parent) and then delete it.

Comment: Concerning this, there are methods [QLayoutItem::widget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html#widget) and [QLayoutItem::layout()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html#layout).